# What is contained within the Cache and CachedData folders in my AppData/Roaming/Code folders (for Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, caching

I have both a `Cache` and a `CachedData` folder Within `C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Roaming\Code\`. What information do these folders contain?

Within the `Cache` folder, I see files such as `data_0` and `f_000020`, some of which are 20+ megabytes in size. Meanwhile, my CachedData folder contains over 1,100 files even though I've only been using this computer for about 10 days. I tried opening a couple of these files in Notepad, but the text appears jumbled and generally illegible.

I'm particularly interested in learning whether these folders potentially contain output data from Jupyter notebooks (even when I've cleared the output from those notebooks); program output shown in the terminal; or program input entered into the Terminal.